# Plotly Express Grouped Violin Distribution not Showing

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, violin-plot

For some reason my plotly express violin graph does not show the distribution in the "violin" part of the graph, opting only to show the box plot. The odd part is I was unable to replicate the problem with sample code (as this is work related I cannot share the source code). Has anyone else experienced this problem? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohNxc.jpg)